# How do I recover a home directory after an upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, encryption, home-directory

I had a home directory in Ubuntu 10.04 called "mtinsley". The account I setup while upgrading to 11 is "mark". I wanted a new home so I could copy only what I wanted from my old home. Now, I do not see any directories under home except:

```
mark@Mounda:/home$ pwd
/home
mark@Mounda:/home$ sudo ls -la
[sudo] password for mark: 
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 2011-06-10 20:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 2011-06-10 21:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 2011-06-10 20:57 .ecryptfs
drwx------ 27 mark mark 4096 2011-06-14 20:08 mark
mark@Mounda:/home$
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with me making my home directory (of the new account, "mark") encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

I was under the impression that the encryption option was always stored as private or .private ( which I knew I could not be trusted with!) was accessed using a live cd using this command.

`sudo find / -type d -iname '.Private' 2>/dev/null`

It should then illustrate a location for your private folder like this

`/media/<disk>/.ecryptfs/<user>/.Private`
`/media/<disk>/<user>/.Private`

There is then a guide on how to remount this folder here: [Encrypted Private Directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory): Scroll down to the section marked **'Live CD method of opening a encrypted home directory'**

Hope that helps

Comment: I followed the instructions. All my mounted dirs and files have weird names like :  ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FXbQuifrK4XnbUQkr9T1ZKVt6pWa178p0BJA.-WxcXNc7ExJx4Y5Lj24DRVWfi2X.flyarKr7OEUqEQ-

Is that because I have the wrong passphrase (I'm wondering if I forgot it).

Comment: i would imagine that is the case. Can you access them?

Comment: I can access them from the command-line. Not from the GUI though, that makes the GUI crash.